# Alternative to APLAY for Mac OS X bash

Tags: macos, bash

Anybody knows any Mac alternative for Linux's APLAY program? I would like to run this script:

```
echo "main(i){for(i=0;;i++)putchar(((i*(i>>8|i>>9)&46&i>>8))^(i&i>>13|i>>6));}" | gcc -x c - && ./a.out | aplay
```

Which makes great sound effect, but I don't know how, since Mac OS doesn't have **aplay**.

**EDIT:**

[Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aplay) to Wikipedia, which describes the functionality of aplay.

Comment: What does aplay do?

Comment: See edit, linked url.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net) utility stands in for aplay.

Answer (score 12):

Here is the same program, as a perl one-liner, which works (tested) on Mac, Linux, and Windows

```
perl -e 'for($i=0;;$i++){
    print pack("n", ((($i*($i>>8|$i>>9)&46&$i>>8))^($i&$i>>13|$i>>6))); 
}' | ./play -c 1 -b 8 -e unsigned -t raw -r 8k -
```

the "./play" command is the "sox" utility already mentioned in this article.

Comment: aplay uses 8khz not 48... so the command should rather be `play -c 1 -b 8 -e unsigned -t raw -r 8k -`

Answer (score 7):

I know that this topic is old, but I've find a recent working solution. SOX doesn't support input from stdout anymore so now a working alternative is `mplayer`. You'll need to install it using [Hombrew.sh](http://brew.sh/) with `brew install mplayer`.

You can then replace `aplay` by:
`mplayer -cache 1024 -quiet -rawaudio samplesize=1:channels=1:rate=8000 -demuxer rawaudio -`

Just be sure to change `rate=8000` with your custom frequency.

You can create an alias in `~/.bashrc` for aplay to pipe your PCM chiptune in like this:

`alias aplay="mplayer -cache 1024 -quiet -rawaudio samplesize=1:channels=1:rate=8000 -demuxer rawaudio -"`

Hope this helped, tested on macOs Sierra 10.12.5 today.

Answer (score 5):

`aplay` needs [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) which is only available on Linux. You could try outputting that bytestream to a file and try to play with `afplay` on OS X. (You likely need to add proper AIFF headers for `afplay` to accept the file since it won't play a raw PCM dump (or however that bytestream coming out of that echo should be interpreted).)

Comment: The fun part about the aplay and this little C algorithm is that it changes and generates different sounds over time, so outputting it would take that away :(

Comment: See it as a longer time delay for buffering playback. :-) how is that data to be interpreted? That might help to find a suitable command line utility that works on OS X to play the data generated by the utility. (For example that might work with mpg123 though I haven't tried that yet.)

Comment: So what would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

I used mpv. The options are similar to mplayer, but the --rawaudio switch is no longer supported in mpv. This is what you do instead:

```
echo 'c_program' | gcc and crap | mpv --cache=1024 --quiet \
    --demuxer=rawaudio \
    --demuxer-rawaudio-format=u8 \
    --demuxer-rawaudio-channels=1 \
    --demuxer-rawaudio-rate=8000 -
```

Comment: I got a bit confused with "gcc and crap", but I figured out that you were just referring to the params passed to the compiler. Works really well, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Install sox from Homebrew, then use `play -c1 -b8 -eunsigned -traw -r8k -` instead of `auplay`.

Answer (score 1):

I already had `ffplay` installed as part of `ffmpeg`, so this was what worked most easily for me:

```
echo "main(i){for(i=0;;i++)putchar(((i*(i>>8|i>>9)&46&i>>8))^(i&i>>13|i>>6));}" \
    | gcc -w -x c - && ./a.out | ffplay -f s16le /dev/stdin
```

See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174639/how-can-i-play-raw-pcm-file-that-i-dumped-from-a-codec

Answer (score 1):

macOS includes a command named `afplay`, which plays an audio file to the default audio output.

To play a file, simply run:

```
afplay <audiofile>
```